# dart pub global packages run twice on windows 10

Tags: dart

Dart Global Packages install with

> pub global activate

always run twice on my windows 10 machine

---

```
Dart SDK version: 2.13.4 (stable)
```

[image]

Comment: I raised [an issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/pub/issues/3262) regarding this as also have the same problem. Feel free to up-vote or look for a solution there when it is addressed by pub team.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found is editing the .bat file from

***C:\Users\$Username\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\bin***

---

**Original bat file**

```
  @echo off
  rem This file was created by pub v2.13.4.
  rem Package: dart_clean
  rem Version: 0.1.3
  rem Executable: dart_clean
  rem Script: main
  if exist  "C:\Users\EBrain\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\global_packages\dart_clean\bin\main.dart-2. 13.4.snapshot" (
  dart "C:\Users\EBrain\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\global_packages\dart_clean\bin\main.dart-2.13.4.snapshot" %*
  rem The VM exits with code 253 if the snapshot version is out-of-date.
  rem If it is, we need to delete it and run "pub global" manually.
  if not errorlevel 253 (
    goto error
  )
  pub global run dart_clean:main %*
  ) else (
  pub global run dart_clean:main %*
  )
  goto eof
  :error
  exit /b %errorlevel%
  :eof
```

**Edited bat file**

```
@echo off
rem This file was created by pub v2.13.4.
rem Package: dart_clean
rem Version: 0.1.3
rem Executable: dart_clean
rem Script: main
pub global run dart_clean:main %*

goto eof
:error
exit /b %errorlevel%
:eof
```

but everytime I update the packages or activate the new package I have to go back and edit the bat file, which is really inconvenient.

It's there any legit way to prevent pub global packages run twice.